# Is there a way to force enable Reader View in Firefox on pages where the icon doesn't appear?

Tags: firefox

My initial question was "What determines if a page can or can't be displayed in Reader View in Firefox?" but I found the answer on a [Webmasters StackExchange question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83058/how-do-i-make-my-site-compatible-with-firefoxs-reader-view-feature).

As far as I understand, sites that don't automatically show the option to enable Reader View have a problem with their code/tag/html/something.
The [Firefox support page for Reader View](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-reader-view-clutter-free-web-pages) suggests something similar:

> If a page is available in Reader View, the Reader View icon will appear in the address bar.

My question now is, if Reader View icon doesn't appear, is there a way to force enable Reader View on such pages?

I read [this Reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/472yw2/update_is_there_a_way_to_always_use_reader_view/) but it doesn't answer my question.

I considered posting this question in [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) but I'm not sure an addon will provide a solution. Maybe this can be done with a script or a Firefox setting in `about:config` or something else entirely?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**Solution 1: The Best One**

You can try installing [Activate Reader View](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-US/firefox/addon/activate-reader-view/), an add-on for Firefox that will force reader view even if the icon is not displayed.

This add-on adds a button to the toolbar. Clicking on it will (force) activate Reader View even if the icon in the address bar is not present.

Technically this Add-on prepends "about:reader?url=" to the current tab's address.

---

**Solution 2: Manual**

Use Reader View on any site/webpage by adding below prefix to the url in the address bar:

> about:reader?url=

For example, to view `https://example.com/page1.html` in Reader View,
enter `about:reader?url=https://example.com/page1.html` in the address bar and proceed.

**Note**: Doesn't work always.

---

**Solution 3: For older version of Firefox**

Install [Pentadactyl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/pentadactyl/) add-on for firefox and create a custom command:

> :command reader execute "open about:reader?url=" + content.location.href

And then you type `:reader` to get the Reader View.

You can also map a keyboard shortcut to your custom command like so...

> :nmap  :reader

A simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> will force Reader View.

**Note**: Pentadactyl is (probably) no longer in development. Last release was in March 15, 2014 and works with Firefox 24.0 - 31.*

Comment: Prepending `about:reader?url=` was the winner for me.  I don't want to become dependent on extensions and none of the other answers worked.

Comment: This is the proper answer right here https://superuser.com/a/1716485/194248

Answer (score 9):

I added the following to my [userChrome.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserChrome.css) file:

```
#reader-mode-button { 
    display: -moz-box !important; 
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

This makes the icon in the address (aka awesome) bar always be displayed. Clicking on it in a page that isn't an article probably won't work. But it ensures that I can go to reader mode quickly on any page where it does work.

Answer (score 4):

> As a user [pointed out](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/activate-reader-view/reviews/1439021/), setting `reader.parse-on-load.force-enabled` to
> `true` (boolean) using `about:config` will force the icon to be visible as well, without the need to install this add-on.

From the comment page for the [Activate Reader View](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/activate-reader-view/) extension (lightly edited).

Comment: This should be accepted answer, really

Comment: Could it be that this setting "does not / does no longer" exist in the latest firefox `114.0`? I did create this setting by using the plus icon but it still does not show up on a certain page.

Comment: No longer works. See [mozilla bug #1696698](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1696698).